# Which bittorrent clients can download preview chunk first?

Tags: bittorrent

Is there a way to tell uTorrent or other BT clients to download the first 1 or 2 or 3% first?

It cannot be quite disturbing when downloading a clip using BT clients and it is 80% done but the first 1% of the clip is not done yet, so you still have to keep waiting for unknown time.

**Update:** title is changed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

uTorrent does this, and I definitely recommend this torrent client as it is fast and extremely lightweight. Starts up within 1 second for me.

To set this option in uTorrent, click Options -> Preferences.

Select Advanced Preferences.

Find the option named "bt.prio_first_last_piece" and set to true.

This will download the start of the file which will let you preview most video files first.

Answer (score 0):

rtorrent with the front-end [rutorrent](https://github.com/Novik/ruTorrent) does this. Go to right-lower pane of your selected torrent task, then go to the Files sub-column.

Right click a file you get a Download Strategy select box with three options: Normal, Leading Chunk First, and Trailing Chunk First.

Answer (score -2):

the direct answer to your question is "Yes".

but not all of them, and no, i wont tell you which ones because you didnt ask that question, you asked if bt clients "can", so...

note: not all of the ones that do support doing this at on first setup, because it breaks some of the basic flow/logic of bt chunk swarming, to spread the load out so that there is some more spread of who as what chunks, should large parts of the swarm go offline.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/919512/ may have some answers to what your are actually asking, and looking for

Comment: I didn't vote you down but I think it's petty to not provide info you know the OP needs.